# How to make a command run after login and x start?

Tags: linux, xorg, arch-linux, autostart, manjaro

I need to run `xset led 3` after every login how can I do do this? I am on Manjaro using gnome.

Comment: Have you seen this page? http://askubuntu.com/questions/30931/how-do-i-make-a-program-auto-start-every-time-i-log-in

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I don't want to use the top method. I could just start it like I start Guake but Don't know how to turn the command into a application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a display manager (for example the Gnome-native [GDM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM), take a look at [~/.xprofile](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xprofile), place your command in there to invoke it after the x server has started, but before any gnome is loaded. If you are using a bare-bones `startx` or `xinit` approach, take a look at [~/.xinitrc](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinit), place your command after the whole resource-merging section, but before the `exec gnome-session`.

If you want the command to run even in ungraphical logins (such as ssh or serial logins) you are out of luck, since xset needs a running x server.